# How to stop combo box from auto select first item when loading from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having trouble stopping the combo box from triggering events as it selects the 1st item when i fill it from database

```
Ds3.Clear();

Da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from Details where Details.Profision= '" + cb_profision.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'and details.Department= '" + cb_department.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", con);
Da2.Fill(Ds3);

name.DataSource = Ds3;
name.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Can you share the code for how you fill your combobox? And what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: show the code. you can add a boolean flag to the form which you set to true while the combobox is populated, and suppress event handling as long as this flag is set.

Comment: this is the part of the code where the query happens and returns value i just want the data loaded but still the combobox appears blank till i drop it down and select the item

Comment: Before you do you anything you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. My friend bobby tables loves this style of code. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SeanLange if you are talking about sql injections iam only getting the item text from another combo box to select so no injections but thx for the headsup

Comment: @MahmoudAshraf even if you think you are in control of the input, it is always a good practice to do parameterised requests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this... Instead of using the `name.SelectionChanged` event in your code you should subscribe instead to `name.SelectionChangeCommitted` event:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx

The `SelectionChangeCommitted` event only fires when a USER changes the selection, not when the control is bound to data. If you want the ComboBox to still have no selected item after it is bound, you need to also add to the end of your code sample:

```
name.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: this didn't work as the compiler detects error in BindingSource   "ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'BindingSource' and no extension method 'BindingSource' accepting a first argument of type 'ComboBox' could be found "

Comment: Well is your app a Winforms app or a web app? asp.net? MVC? WPF?

Comment: its a Disk top app (Winforms)